# How to reset a file edited with edit-json-file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs, discord.js

I've been working on this queue for a discord.js bot. What it does it someone does !smm submit  and then it will add it to the JSON file like so:

```
"1": "id",
"2": "anotherid"
```

Then if a person were to do !smm delete it would remove the first item in the list. For some reason if I do that it will keep the same amount of objects but instead it will duplicated the last object so if my JSON file was this

```
"1": "id",
"2": "anotherid",
"3": "thisid"
```

It would be at the end

```
"1": "anotherid",
"2": "thisid",
"3": "thisid"
```

If you have a better way for a queue please tell me otherwise here is my code for the command and its subcommands. There is a editJsonFile api installed so when you see "queue.set("foo", "foobar")" foo is the object name and foobar is the object's value:

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}smm`){
    let type = args[0];
    let a = args[1];
    if(type === "submit"){
        message.delete()
        if(a){
            if(a.charAt(4) === "-" && a.charAt(9) === "-" && a.charAt(14) === "-"){
                for(x = 1; x < 10000; x++){
                    if(!file[x]){
                        console.log(x)
                        queue.set(`${x}`, `${a}`)
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                message.author.send("Sorry but you typed in the ID wrong. Make sure you include these '-' to separate it.")
            }
        }
    }
    if(type === "delete"){
        message.delete()
        let arr = [];
        for(x = 1; x < 10000; x++){
            if(file[x]){
                arr.push(file[x])
            }else{

                let arrr = arr.slice(1)
                console.log(arrr)
                fs.writeFile(`./queue.json`, '{\n    \n}', (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    };
                });
                setTimeout(function(){

                    console.log(arrr.length)
                    for(e = 0; e < arrr.length; e++){
                        console.log(`e: ${e} || arrr.length: ${arrr.length}`)
                        queue.set(`${e+1}`, `${arrr[e]}`)
                    }

                    return;
                }, 3000)
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found out your problem: at line 32, you're "resetting" the file with `fs.writeFile`. Since the file is cached by [editJsonFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file), re-writing the file has no effect on your queue variable, and when you set another value the package internally rewrites the previously cached values.

To avoid that, you can reset the variable after calling [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) (or [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)). Here's a little example I've tested with [RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/edit-json-file):

```
var editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");
var fs = require("fs");

var file = editJsonFile(`./queue.json`); //load queue.json

file.set("1", "foo"); //set your values
file.set("2", "bar");

console.log(file.get()); //this logs "{1: "foo", 2: "bar"}"

fs.writeFileSync(`./queue.json`, '{\n    \n}'); //reset queue.json

file = editJsonFile(`./queue.json`); //reload the file <---- this is the most important one

file.set("3", "test"); //set your new variables

console.log(file.get()); //this logs "{3: "test"}"
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked and is way better than my solution which wasn’t very effective.